IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface blabla, but class was expected
I'm receiving crash reports from my Android app. They started when I called a private interface method from within a default method. The original code is huge, so here's a simplified version:
public interface MyInterface {
    private void myPrivateMethod() {
        // ... Some code ...
    }
    default void interfaceMethod() {
        myPrivateMethod();
    }
}

Here's the generated Bytecode (obfuscated, sorry!):
 public s() { //()V
         aload0 // reference to self
         invokespecial c1/q.o()V
         return
 }

I get the following exception:

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface c1.q, but class was expected

at c1.q.s(Unknown Source:1)


It appears that invokespecial is used instead of invokeinterface, when this is an interface and not a class.
interfaceMethod is called as following:
public interface MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override public void interfaceMethod() {
        MyInterface.super.interfaceMethod();
        
        // ... other code ...
    }
}

Everything is my project's code. I'm not calling any libraries in this process, it's just my code calling my code, so I don't understand how this issue took place.
I'm not sure who is at fault here, and I can't reproduce the issue no matter what. I am doubting R8, but I just have crash reports from only a few devices. We have multiple reports from the same devices, giving the impression that the app is consistently crashing there. All the devices are fairly new running Android 14.
I'm thinking of turning myPrivateMethod into a static method with the next release, but I would love to get an explanation.
